# How to get instance of Service Provider in program.cs and pass it as parameter to another method call in .net 6

Tags: .net-6.0, service-provider

I have need to call external static method from within program.cs and pass a reference to Service Provide

```
       var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            // PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.,
            WriteIndented = true,
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
        };

     
        var url = "https://XXXXXXXX/";
        var setting = new RefitSettings
        {
            ContentSerializer = new SystemTextJsonContentSerializer(options),
            AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter = () => Task.FromResult(GetToken(sp)),
        };

        builder.Services.AddRefitClient<IApplicationApi>(setting)
        .ConfigureHttpClient(c =>
        {
            c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(url);
        });
```

GetToken is also defined inside program.cs

```
  private static async Task<string> GetToken(IServiceProvider  provider)
        {
            var _JsRuntime = provider.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
           var token = await _JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("localStorage.getItem", "AuthToken");
            return "No Token";
        }
```